# How to handle very long sentences in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tying to using Text component for explain the terms and conditions
but If I enter more than 15000 characters then error occurred with "ArgumentException: Mesh can not have more than 65000 vertices"

So is there any good way for handle very long sentences in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to get around this limit we will need to split the text across multiple meshes. You can do this by either;

- using multiple gameObjects with individual Text components
- use a solution that created multiple meshes for long texts. I would recommend trying TextMeshPro (Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html)

Comment: I'd recommend TextMeshPro, it's much more robust than the old Unity's Text, and is now an integral part of Unity since they purchased them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have also considered TextMeshPro, but I have to include Thai Language in the current project, so I am worried that the capacity of the app will increase if I add fonts.